# Retrieve images which match parameter value

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I try to get images that match with the parameter value but it returns only a single image(first image in DB). my images are saved as binary in DB

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/GetImages")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetImages(int productId)
    {

        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        
        IEnumerable<ProductImage> files = _context.ProductImages.Where(p => p.ProductId == productId);
        foreach (var item in files)
        {
            response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(item.Image);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = item.Image.LongLength;

            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = item.Name;

            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(item.ContentType);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ProductImage file = _context.ProductImages.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == producId);`

the way this line is written, using FirstOrDefault, will only ever return the first ProductImage it finds matching the productId.

I believe what you're looking for should be more like

`IEnumerable<ProductImage> files = _context.ProductImages.Where(p => p.ProductId == producId);`

The `for` loop you have written will also not work how you expect it, if you try and fetch productId 100, <s>it will loop 100 times, setting the content of your response to the same picture 100 times.</s>
After re-reading and noticing the `return` at the end of your loop, it will always stop after the first iteration.

You'll probably want to do a `foreach` loop over `files` and add them to your response with something like this: [What's the best way to serve up multiple binary files from a single WebApi method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266422/whats-the-best-way-to-serve-up-multiple-binary-files-from-a-single-webapi-metho)

Comment: Thanks for ur help. I used foreach loop and I'm still getting 1 image. I'll update the question with my current code.

Comment: You're still resetting the response.Content each loop, the answer I linked shows you should be creating a MultipartContent object outside of the loop, populating it inside the loop, then set your response.Content to the MultipartContent object after your loop